# Getting an error while selecting the language of MS Script Control 1.0 as Perl Script

Tags: vb6, perlscript, msscriptcontrol

In my VB 6 application, I am using  `Script Control 1.0` for running external scripts through my application. But while running, I am getting the below error.

```
"Error running Perl script: A script engine for the specified language can not be created."
```

I've installed ActivePerl 5.14 and the error is occurring while running the code below:

```
Dim perl As New ScriptControl
perl.Language = "PerlScript"
```

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that matching language engine can not be found.

Make sure that you do select `PerlScript` when installing Active Perl (it *is* selected by default, at least in the latest version):

[image]

Successful installation creates `PerlScript` key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive. This key should have `CLSID` subkey with CLSID of Active Script language engine. Component having this CLSID should be registered in the system. In my installation the component's binary is `C:\Perl\bin\PerlSE.dll`.